# Python: How to convert matrix to ASCII string?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I wanna ask about how to convert matrix to string then convert to text?
For example I have matrices from image and have range from 0 - 255:

```
[[224 65 90]  
[62 125 33]  
[75 40 94]]
```

I want the output is convert all matrix value to ASCII text with string type like this:

> 'àAZ>}!K(^'

The code:

```
slices = Image.Image.split(image)
channel_red = np.array(slices[0])

# Matrix to string code below
???
```

Comment: Please, check [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do what you asked:

```
import numpy as np
m=np.array([[224, 65, 90],
[62 ,125 ,33],
[75 ,40 ,94]])
print(''.join(map(chr,m.flatten())))
```

Updated based on rioV8's comment - no need for a list after `join`.

**Output**:

```
Out[34]: 'àAZ>}!K(^'
```

Comment: Aah its work, thanks!
Btw im new in here, sorry for bad question.

Comment: @MohamadAbyannaufal No worries. If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: `list()` is not needed, `join()` can handle an iterable